# How to install node packages in ubuntu server with IPv6 only

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04, nvm

I'm trying to install typescript on an Ubuntu server where only IPv6 address space is available.

I'm getting error as follows. Any help?

```
:/home/dev/.nvm# npm install --global typescript
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-01T19_15_39_294Z-debug.log
```

The error of this network connectivity happens with many packages and even github. I installed nvm in a slightly different way by setting the codebase in bitbucket.

I tried to install npm and n to setup typescript using n. That failed and I started using nvm as alternative. PFB the logs when trying to install n.

```
    :~# sudo npm install -g n
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect ENETUNREACH ::ffff:151.101.208.162:80 - Local (:::0)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

I just need some way to get it installed but no luck! I strongly believe it is IPv6 issue and looking for work around.

Btw, my ubuuntu server is 16.04.3 LTS. I have installed it successfully on IPv4 servers running on Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04 version and here in Production, I'm locked!

Comment: can you try `nslookup registry.npmjs.org` and tell me the output

Comment: Here it is;    `Server:         2001:550:1:1::d
Address:        2001:550:1:1::d#53

Non-authoritative answer:
registry.npmjs.org      canonical name = a.sni.fastly.net.
Name:   a.sni.fastly.net
Address: 151.101.20.162`

Comment: btw, whats your node and npm versions as well

Comment: I'm using node v9.0.0 and npm v5.5.1

Comment: I've updated my own answer below. Hope it will help somebody!

Comment: thanks for uploading your fix, this will a lot of people who're stuck atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that working after a change in registry. Could be a network problem that I faced on server OR the IPv6 only issue. Anyway the change in registry worked perfect.

```
sudo npm --registry http://registry.node-modules.io/ install n -g
```

After all the link below guided me to the answer.
[Node-modules.io](https://node-modules.io/)

Hope this will help somebody for the future reference!
Thanks for @Kalana Demel for the help to reach me to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround which will also work for yarn, is to add the resolved ip6s to /etc/hosts :

```
2606:4700::6810:1723 registry.yarnpkg.com
2606:4700::6810:1723 registry.npmjs.org
2606:4700::6810:ab63 yarnpkg.com
```

You can get the ip6s with `nslookup registry.yarnpkg.com`, `nslookup …`.

Comment: I added the `registry.npmjs.org` to my `/etc/hosts` and everything is peachy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue might be with proxy setting try using http instead of https, ipv6 issues seems to be resolved in the newer versions of npm as well.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean
```

**Update**

It seems that the issue which was supposed to be fixed in 8.5.0 is still there, so for IPV6 only networks npm is still not working even though Node is now passing the necessary flags, so till it's fixed you will have to find a workaround.

For more info : [Node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/14731),  [NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18941)

Comment: I tried this with --force without success. It is now giving the error - `http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed` when I tried the following command - `nvm install-latest-npm`